# OpenAPI Generator - typescript - How to set API key?

Tags: openapi-generator

Using the [OpenAPI typescript Generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/typescript), how do you set an API key?

This is how you do it using the [typescript-fetch generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/typescript-fetch)

```
const api = new DefaultApi(new Configuration({ 
  apiKey: apiEndpoints.warnings_api_key, 
  basePath
}))
```

But the [typescript (experimental) generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/typescript) doesn't seem to accept `apiKey`.

Answer (score 0):

Via the `credentials`:

```
export function apiConfigFactory(): Configuration {
  const params: ConfigurationParameters = {
    basePath: '/api',
    credentials: {
      "ApiKeyAuth": "my-secret-key"
    }
  };
  return new Configuration(params);
}
```

If you OpenAPI specifies:

```
//...
  "security": [
    {
      "ApiKeyAuth": []
    }
  ],
  "components": {
    "securitySchemes": {
      "ApiKeyAuth": {
        "type": "apiKey",
        "name": "auth",
        "in": "query"
      }
    }
  }
//...
```